# Struts2 <s:select> list filled with jsp expression

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I am trying to create a form using a map for each object in form.
When I iterate thought the map, it will recognize if it's a textfield or something else. My problem starts with `<s:select/>`.

I have to fill all data from the map, but I can't get list when I am using jsp expression `<%= %>` to put there the right key.

**MyAction.java**

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1219003996856257128L;

    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public String populate() {
        // get all attributes ... 
        // for each put data in map... 
        // in .jsp create txtfields / txtareas / checkboxes, depends on attribute type... 
        // <s:select /> not working
        // example with single attribute

        Attribute<?> attr = Attribute.getTestList();

        //map.put("testList", "prd");

        // 'testList' x 'prd'
        map.put(attr.getName(), attr.getValue());

        // when attribute is list, i will put into map it's List<String> (ArrayList<String>)
        // with all possible values
        // key is same as selected value's key with suffix '_data'
        if(attr.isList()) {

            //List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            //list.add("---");
            //list.add("prd");
            //list.add("kak");
            //map.put("testList_data", list);

            // 'testList_data' x 'List<String> => {"---", "prd", "kak"}'
            map.put(attr.getName() + "_data", ((ListAttribute) attr).getPossibleValuesAsList());

        }
        return "fill";
    }

    public String execute() {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

**page.jsp**

```
<s:form id='form' action='submit' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
    <!-- test list attribute, contains name, value and list of possible values -->
    <% 
    Attribute<?> attr = Attribute.getTestList();
    %>
    <!-- store input's name -->
    <s:set var='inputName'>map['<%= attr.getName() %>']</s:set>
    <%
        if(attr.isList()) {
    %>

    <!-- store input's list -->
    <s:set var='listData'>map['<%= attr.getName() + "_data" %>']</s:set>
    <!-- not working -->
    <s:select list='%{listData}' name="%{inputName}" />

    <!-- key filled manually - working, but useless for me -->
    <s:select list="map['testList_data']" name="%{inputName}" />
    <%
        }
     %>
    <sj:submit id='sumbitButton' value='AbrakaDabra' targets="myAjaxTarget"/>
</s:form>
<div id="myAjaxTarget"></div>
```

The problem is when I try to set the list attribute in the `<s:select/>` tag. I tried it similar way like with names (or ids or anything else) but it didn't work.

Does anyone know why is name filled and working correctly but list isn't?

```
s:select list='%{listData}' name="%{inputName}"
```

As you can see on the following images , first select have only one (corrupted) option. At second picture you can see ideal result which I want, but I need it with jsp expression.

**Whole form:**

[image]

**Ideal result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using Scriptlets, and try to do it with OGNL.

The code needed to obtain the desired result should be similar to the following:

```
<s:select list="map['%{#attr.attr.name}_data']" name="%{#attr.attr.name}" />
```

Comment: So it't impossible to use Scriplets to set list attribute to select tag? Because I'm not sure if this will help me when I will try to apply this on more dynamic attributes.

Comment: What it's not clear in your question is that you have no loops. Is the whole form inside a (not posted) iterator ? And most of all, WHY aren't you simply iterating the map reading its values without the need of constructing them, and using that attribute stuff at all ?

Comment: @TomášPletánek: You shouldn't use scriplets at all. You can achieve same result using tags.